# Structured Streaming delta file does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am running spark2.2.1 structured streaming,the program failed after some time because the file did not exist,I fount this in [enter link description here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19268)
,but it didn't work for me.And then I think the question might be checkpoint,I changed my code to the following
`

```
    Dataset<Row> df = this.spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
                .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                .load();
                ……
 StreamingQuery start = result.writeStream()
                .foreach(new CrossVhcLaneForeach(kafkaProperties, laneTopic))
                .outputMode("update")
                .option("checkpointLocation", this.checkPointLocation+"/laneDir")
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(Long.parseLong(delayTime),TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .start();
```

`
But then the program will be in a kind of suspended animation, it won't stop running, it won't give an error,I hope someone has a way to help me. Thanks.
I used java1.8, spark2.2.1standalone, hadoo2.7.3.The mistakes I encountered are as follows:

---

```
19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 979, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 5, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 976, 34.55.0.164, executor 1): java.lang.IllegalS
tateException: Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=4), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta does not exist        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$str
eaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:410)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$exec
ution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:362)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$exec
ution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$exec
ution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$exec
ution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$str
eaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.getStore(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvi
der.scala:265)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.get(StateStore.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta does
 not exist        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$str
eaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:407)        ... 21 more

19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 980, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 4, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 978) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=3), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 1]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 981, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 3, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 979) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=5), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 1]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 982, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 5, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 981) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=3), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 2]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 983, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 3, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.1 in stage 13.0 (TID 980) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=4), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 1]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 984, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 4, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 982) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=5), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/5/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 2]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 985, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 5, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.2 in stage 13.0 (TID 984) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=4), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/4/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 2]19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 986, 34.55.0.164, executor 1, partition 4, AN
Y, 4730 bytes)19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 983) on 34.55.0.164, executor 1: java.lang.Illega
lStateException (Error reading delta file /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=3), dir = /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3]: /tmp/temporary-507089d7-9a64-40aa-9e8e-ab8a276f5bcf/state/0/3/1.delta does not exist) [duplicate 3]19/01/24 10:50:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 13
19/01/24 10:50:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 13 was cancelled
```

Comment: Its a bit late but anyway , I faced the exact same issue with pyspark 2.4.2 . Eventually i had change my checkpointing directory and the topic name too . Strange but it worked

Comment: same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Spark saves/stores streaming states in checkpoint locations (hdfs if you've preferred). if a particular state stopped abruptly/failed (for example losing an executor in dynamic nodes allocation app).. spark can't pick from it... The solution is to clear the offset and start again(it mainly depends on use case)